# ROS2 Eloquent installation failed in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, ros2

Referring to this [link](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Eloquent/Linux-Install-Debians/), I am installing ROS2 Eloquent into my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

My system's information is as below (via **uname -a**)

```
Linux myname 5.3.0-28-generic #30~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 06:14:09 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I could **Setup Locale** and **Setup Sources** with no issue. Then, it came to **Install ROS 2 packages**.

After running **sudo apt update**,I ran **sudo apt install ros-eloquent-desktop** and it returned:

```
  The following packages will be upgraded:
    cpp-7 g++-7 gcc-7 gcc-7-base libasan4 libcilkrts5 libdrm-amdgpu1
  libdrm-common libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libexif12
  libgcc-7-dev libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libicu60 libjpeg-turbo8 libjson-c3
  libopenexr22 libpython2.7 libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib
  libpython3.6 libpython3.6-minimal libpython3.6-stdlib libsqlite3-0 libssl1.1
  libstdc++-7-dev libubsan0 libuuid1 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0
  libwayland-egl1 libwayland-server0 libxml2 python3.6 python3.6-minimal
38 upgraded, 881 newly installed, 0 to remove and 196 not upgraded.
    Need to get 9,381 kB/432 MB of archives.
    After this operation, 1,967 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gcc-7 amd64 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
    Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gcc-7 amd64 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
      Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
    E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-7/gcc-7_7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
    E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I truncated the response to only keep the last part which I think will help you to know what's wrong. I googled but could not find the solution. I don't have any firewall and antivirus installed as well.

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I have actually resolved my issue but I think your way is more proper. It can serve as my remedy if I encounter similar issue in future. Anyway, what I did was:

I ended up downloading the deb package directly from http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-7/gcc-7_7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb followed by installing it via the commands (ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt)

```
sudo dpkg -i path_to_the_deb
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt update
```

Then, I was able to install ros-eloquent-desktop.